# convert boolean[] to boolean

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, boolean

so lets say I have this code:

```
private static boolean[] between nums(double[] numbers, double thisNumber)
    int i = 0;
int length = numbers.length;
boolean [] r = new boolean [length];
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    double oneWord = values[i];
    if ((oneDouble >= (thisNumber)
    {
        r.equals(true);
    }
}
return r;
```

r is not returning true. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I printed out the variable r, it gave me a bunch of really weird digits. Is there a way that I can convert boolean[] to boolean, or am I on the right track here?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? There's a few odd things here. Show a [mcve] and describe the problem you're having.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: The requirement is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you share a sample input and the output you're trying to get for it?

Comment: I added an answer to make things more clear: @JoeC

Comment: What you posted is not an answer, and you should not post it as such.  You should click the [edit] button instead and make your clarifications there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a `boolean[]` as to which values are at least the number you are looking for you can do.

```
private static boolean[] atLeast(double[] numbers, double thisNumber)
    boolean[] results = new boolean[number.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++
        results[i] = number[i] >= thisNumber;
    return results;
}
```

Or if you return a `List<Boolean>`

```
private static List<Boolean> atLeast(double[] numbers, double thisNumber)
    return DoubleStream.of(numbers)
                       .mapToObj(d -> d >= thisNumber)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

It appears that you are looking for a method to return true if there is a value at least as big as the number.

```
private static boolean atLeast(double[] numbers, double thisNumber)
    for (double d : numbers)
        if (d >= thisNumber)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Using streams you could write

```
private static boolean atLeast(double[] numbers, double thisNumber)
    return DoubleStream.of(numbers)
                       .anyMatch(d >= thisNumber)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when I use "return true" and "return false" it says that boolean can not be converted to boolean []. Because it is an array

Comment: @KristyCompany So you don't want to convert to a boolean but instead want to return a boolean[] of results for each element?

Comment: @KristyCompany If you want to print the result a `List<Boolean>` will print the way you might expect.